# Understanding Theorem on Combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

What following Theorem wants to convey (how there can be infinite repetitions), pls give some examples to explain.[image]

Comment: "infinite" here means the object can be repeated as many times as you like. Since the theorem is looking at $r$-combinations, this really means each object can be repeated up to $r$ times.